# Can I improve performance of a query if I use several subqueries and use their results as condition for the main query?

Tags: c#, sql, performance, sqlite, subquery

(First of all a lot of explaining, the actual question is rather short at the end of the post)

This is the initial situation:
We are developing a software, which queries data from sqlite databases and plots them in different graphs (LineChart, BarChart, ...)
The idea is that the user can select columns for X- and Y- axis as well as any combination of filters and the software will create a query, gets the data and plots it. 
Now we want to improve performance of the query a bit. To do that I take a query the software calculates from a random plot and test it in the [DB Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org) and see how long it takes. Then I try to change the query manually and see if I can improve the time.

For this test we use a big (for sqlite) database with several filters (1.4Gb database size, around 35Mio lines / 6 columns in the table where we want to get a result from.

We have 3 linked tables `EmdTable`, `ShmooTable`and `ResultTable`. 
The software gives me the following query (copied from debugging and removed string escape characters):

```
SELECT (R0), AVG(R1) FROM 
(SELECT (EmdTable."Time [ns]") AS R0, (EmdTable."Upper Sideband [mV]" ) AS R1 FROM EmdTable, ResultTable, ShmooTable 
WHERE EmdTable."ResultID"=ResultTable."ID" 
AND ResultTable."ShmooID"=ShmooTable."ID" 
AND ResultTable."CommandName"="APDU: Get PO" 
AND ResultTable."Repetition"="1" 
AND ResultTable."StepName"="Command" 
AND ShmooTable."Hn [A/m]"="2" 
AND EmdTable."Time [ns]" IS NOT NULL 
AND EmdTable."Upper Sideband [mV]" IS NOT NULL)  
WHERE R0 IS NOT NULL AND R1 IS NOT NULL  GROUP BY R0
```

In the DB browser this takes around 62 seconds to get the result of around 15.000 datapoints (for X and Y)

My idea was to use the filter condition in the subqueries right away instead of joining everything together and the make the conditions. 
My manual query then looked like this:

```
SELECT (R0), AVG(R1) FROM 
(
(SELECT (EmdTable."Time [ns]") AS R0, (EmdTable."Upper Sideband [mV]" ) AS R1, (EmdTable."ResultID") AS ID1 FROM EmdTable) AS emdquery INNER JOIN
(
SELECT ID2 FROM
(SELECT ResultTable.ID AS ID2, ShmooID FROM ResultTable WHERE ResultTable."CommandName"="APDU: Get PO" AND ResultTable."Repetition"="1" AND ResultTable."StepName"="Command" ) AS resultquery INNER JOIN
(SELECT ShmooTable.ID FROM ShmooTable WHERE ShmooTable."Hn [A/m]" = "2") AS shmooquery ON resultquery.ShmooID = shmooquery.ID
) AS subquery ON emdquery.ID1 = subquery.ID2
)WHERE R0 IS NOT NULL AND R1 IS NOT NULL  GROUP BY R0
```

Now behold: this takes only around 60 second...so not quite the performance improvements I was hoping for.

However the 'subquery' on its own (the one within the big query above) only takes around 15ms and returns only 3 values. 
If I now use these three values directly to query my results from `EmdTable`like this:

```
SELECT EmdTable."Time [ns]", AVG(EmdTable."Upper Sideband [mV]") FROM EmdTable 
WHERE (EmdTable.ResultID = 1102 OR EmdTable.ResultID = 4818 OR EmdTable.ResultID = 8510) AND EmdTable."Time [ns]" IS NOT NULL AND EmdTable."Upper Sideband [mV]" IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY  EmdTable."Time [ns]"
```

It will 'only' take about 40 seconds for the same results as the first two queries. Improvement of 20 seconds...not bad.

**This brings me to the actual question(s):**

1. I could query the the subquery first programmatically (15ms) and
   inserte the result into the main query, again programmatically,
   which shouldn't take much longer than the 40 seconds, right?
2. Is there another way to do this operation directly using only sql?

Comment: Maybe you should be building some indexes on your tables.

Comment: Well that's the problem...I have no influence on the databases themselves whatsoever

Comment: 1.4GB  and using SQLite? Drop SQLite and install PostgreSQL, man. You need the big guns now.

Comment: again: no influence on the database. Also: for this example I searched for a extreme database, normal usage is with smaller ones

Comment: If you don't have the ability to add indexes to those specific SQLite databases, can you copy them to versions that you do have control over, so that you can create indexes?  Or copy the data to a DBMS with better performance, such as Postgres?

Comment: @rd_nielsen I guess I would have to let the (or a new) software do that, but having to copy everything first kind of destroys the point of performance improvement, doesn't it?

Comment: @RolandDeschain: The time to copy during application startup could be considerably less than the 60 seconds to run this single query.

Comment: The query could definitively benefit from indexes. I can advise on which indexes to create, if you can create indexes, and can provide some extra details on the table data. Let me know if you are interested.

Comment: OK, but the general use is: startup, load database, plot, load next database,...

Comment: Looks like your missing parentheses around your ORs in the last query so I don't think its returning what you want/expect, i.e. any ResultID = 1102 satisfies the whole predicate immediately.

Comment: OK. 1) How name rows does each table have? 2) What percentage of rows does each one of the following six conditions [separately] select out of the total? `ResultTable."CommandName"="APDU: Get PO"`, `ResultTable."Repetition"="1"`, `ResultTable."StepName"="Command"`, `ShmooTable."Hn [A/m]"="2"`, `EmdTable."Time [ns]" IS NOT NULL`, and `EmdTable."Upper Sideband [mV]" IS NOT NULL`; this entails a foew minutes of work, but can provide great benefits to your query(ies).

Comment: @TheImpaler the answer to all of this unfortunately is "it depends" since different databases will be loaded into the software. However my real question is that I want to make the query into several smaller ones (for each table) and then use those results for the main query - and if all of that is possible by only using SQL. As stated in OP, this theoretically could save some time

Comment: @AlexK. corrected it, copying mistake.

Comment: For anyone who's interested, I have indexed the test database and run the first query on it...response time is 201ms. Again, doesn't have much to do with my initial question, just wanted it to test also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to question 1 is of course yes, especially if you can use something like LINQ to SQL it would be easy. LINQ converts the method `Contains` to the SQL operator `IN`.

In SQL, can you use the sub-query with `IN`?

```
SELECT EmdTable."Time [ns]", AVG(EmdTable."Upper Sideband [mV]") FROM EmdTable 
WHERE EmdTable.ResultID IN (
    SELECT ResultTable."ID"
    FROM ResultTable, ShmooTable 
    WHERE ResultTable."ShmooID"=ShmooTable."ID" 
          AND ResultTable."CommandName"="APDU: Get PO" 
          AND ResultTable."Repetition"="1" 
          AND ResultTable."StepName"="Command" 
          AND ShmooTable."Hn [A/m]"="2"
)
AND EmdTable."Time [ns]" IS NOT NULL AND EmdTable."Upper Sideband [mV]" IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  EmdTable."Time [ns]"
```

Comment: Ok, I have read somewhere in the meantime, that the answer to the second question is NO, since you can't store intermediate variable values in sqlite. Can you confirm this and include it into your answer? Then I will mark your answer. Thx!

Comment: @RolandDeschain Can you explain how you are creating/sending the SQL to the database? In general, you can use parameterized queries with SQLite and pass in previous results.

Comment: @RolandDeschain Also, what happens with my sample SQL query that uses the sub-query for `IN`?

Comment: Sorry, I was on the wrong foot there. Using `IN` should work (I haven't yet been able to test it, but read up on it and it fits what I was looking for). I will test, if I can improve the speed this way, thank you!

Comment: UPDATE: with the `IN` statement I get the expected improvements of about a third of the query speed.

Comment: @RolandDeschain Great! I guess SQLite optimization could use some work.

Comment: @RolandDeschain I found [this article](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) on the SQLite optimizer that might be useful in the future. In particular, it may be possible to use `CROSS JOIN` and make your original query work by controlling the order of evaluation.